VS Code Extension API - Task Provider - Build Task example (simple)
Background:
This is a duplicate (yes) of previous questions (Extension API - Task Provider - Build Task example) - where I cannot seem to get the answers to work - with the sole purpose of garnering attention. Sorry for posting a duplicate. I would be happy to get advice and to get a working answer somewhere, anywhere... ( Tried commenting to bump the original. What are other approaches for getting an answer to an old question? ) Maybe the APIs have changed (no, I dont think so).
Context:
Want to build a simple vs code extension that will execute a build (render) for certain files - execute a shell script, simply.
Problem: I cant get any of the samples or examples to work.
I am not the smartest on the planet but not stupid - but I am most likely ignorant of some basic thing, here. I tried the rake example, but it gets the same result: "No [...] tasks found." I tried
Question: Can I get a most basic - but working - hello world example of how to execute a shell command as a task?
What have I tried?

Task Provider sample
Simple hello world exampleProvider

(and more, actually, but...) All give the same result... "No [...] tasks found." Gah.
I would love to get the second one to work.
exampleProvider test repo
So, I took the simple hello world example provider example and I put it in a repo here.
As with all others: It builds and runs fine, all 25 lines of code... But it does not work as I expect.
You get the "No [...] tasks found."
It looks like this when debugging it, result:

What am I missing?
Thanks alot for reading my question!
BR!
